# Service Bus Clone from Dead Letter Queue Not Working

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to take a single message from a service bus dead letter queue, clone it and send it back to the original queue. I am using the clone method, then removing dead letter reasons from the userproperties before using SendAsync to send it back.

Two issues I've noticed -- as I remove properties from the new, cloned message, those properties are also being removed from the original message. Also, when I use the SendAsync method, I never see the new message anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
            string fullPath = EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(TopicName, subscriptionName);
            var deadLetterClient = new MessageReceiver(ServiceBusConnectionString, fullDeadLetterPath);
            var client = new MessageSender(ServiceBusConnectionString, fullPath);

            var messages = deadLetterClient.ReceiveAsync(1).Result;
            if (messages.Any())
            {
                var message = messages.First();
                var newMessage = message.Clone();
                newMessage.UserProperties.Remove("DeadLetterReason");
                newMessage.UserProperties.Remove("DeadLetterErrorDescription");

                client.SendAsync(newMessage);
            }
```

Comment: In the immediate window, newMessage == message yields false. Yet the user properties are in fact being removed from both messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

newMessage.UserProperties == message.UserProperties yields true. Apparently there is some type of bug with the clone method where it is not doing a deep clone.

My best guess at this point is I am going to have to manually create a new copy of the message object rather than rely on the clone operation.